# Binary Tree sorting while enter elements

Tags: java, sorting, binary-tree

i am newbie learning java .
i want to make Binary tree that sort the elements

i used this code

```
private void setNode (Node Value, Node head){

    if (head == null || Value.Value == head.Value)
        return;

        if (Value.Value > head.Value) {
            if (head.Right == null) {
                head.Right = Value;
                return;
            } else
                setNode(Value, head.Right);
        }

    if (Value.Value < head.Value){
        if(head.Left == null){
            head.Left = Value;
            return;}
        else
            setNode(Value, head.Left);
    }

}
```

but if i used it like this

```
for (int i=0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
        link.addNode(new Node(i));

BinaryLinkList a = new BinaryLinkList(link);
    a.Search(700);
```

it will find it after 700 try
because every time the number entered this larger than the previous
it will be like this

0

.1

..2

...3

....4

.....5

.......

........

.........700 <<

...........

............1000

i want it to sort while enter the elements one by one not array
any help ?

Comment: Forget Java, write pseudo code in plain English and show us what you want. Sounds like you're after [Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

Comment: You need to learn about Balanced trees.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) is as good a place to start as any.

Answer (score 1):

The worst case for the general concept of a `Binary Tree` is to insert elements in sorted order. You will then exactly experience what you just told us, all elements will be put to one side and you do not gain any advantage from the *tree concept* (the depth is the amount of elements).

For sorting input that may already be sorted you should use other data structures than a `Binary Tree`, there are many concepts with different advantages and disadvantages.

There is also an optimization where you balance a tree after some time. As @Kevin Anderson mentioned you may take a look at [self balancing binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree). Also the implementation coming with the standard Java library is self balancing too ([TreeSet at JavaAPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)). Maybe you are also looking for a `PriorityQueue` ([PriorityQueue at JavaAPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)). There are also multiple concepts of how to implement such a queue (for example as `BucketQueue`), again with advantages and disadvantages.

What is your user case? We can help you find a suitable data-structure if you tell us what you want to implement with it.